# Display Table info when picker item is selected

Tags: xamarin, data-binding, android-sqlite, picker

I am still a beginner so bear with me.

I am trying to change the displayed information (in an ActionSheet and on other pages) based on the selectedItem of a picker. Each item in the picker refers to a column on a table, and has its own row Id (set to autoIncrement).
I am able to save (and display as needed) the current SelectedItem, but only as that items name, and nothing else associated with that row (that I am aware of).

I should be able to use the binding properties of the picker to do this, but it doesn't want to work.
I feel I am missing something stupid.

Xaml.cs

```
using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(App.DatabaseLocation))
            {

                var terms = conn.Table<Terms>().ToList().FirstOrDefault();//Lets me access the columns on the table

                var pickerItem = termPicker.Items[termPicker.SelectedIndex]; //Lets me save and use the TermName

                DisplayActionSheet(PickerItem.TermName, "Ok", null, "Term Status: " + PickerItem.TermStatus,
               "Projected Start: " + PickerItem.TProjStart.ToString(),
               "Projected End: " + PickerItem.TProjEnd.ToString(),
               "Actual Start: " + PickerItem.TActStart.ToString(),
               "Actual End : " + PickerItem.TActEnd.ToString()); ;


            }
```

Xaml

```
<Picker x:Name="termPicker"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Terms}"
                    ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding TermName}"
                    Title="Select a term"
                    IsEnabled="True"
                    SelectedItem="{Binding PickerItem}"/>
```

Table

```
 public class Terms
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string TermName { get; set; } 
        public string TermStatus { get; set; } 
        public DateTime TProjStart { get; set; }
        public DateTime TProjEnd { get; set; } 
        public DateTime TActStart { get; set; } 
        public DateTime TActEnd { get; set; } 
        public Object PickerItem { get; set; }
```

If I use `term.TermName` etc. in the DisplayActionSheet, it works(ish) but only will display what the default values are, regardless of the Picker SelectedItem. If I change the DisplayActionSheet to `PickerItem.TermName` etc., it gives the error "object does not contain a definition for TermName".

I understand that SelectedItem is an object, but I'm not sure how to set that object to reference the Terms table, or the row that the SelectedItem is tied to.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: Adding most current and working code:

```
 public class Terms
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string TermName { get; set; } 
        public string TermStatus { get; set; } 
        public DateTime TProjStart { get; set; }
        public DateTime TProjEnd { get; set; } 
        public DateTime TActStart { get; set; } 
        public DateTime TActEnd { get; set; }
```

OnAppearing

```
 protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();

            using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(App.DatabaseLocation))
            {
                conn.CreateTable<Terms>();
                conn.CreateTable<Courses>();
                conn.CreateTable<Assessments>();

                var terms = conn.Table<Terms>().ToList();
                var courses = conn.Table<Courses>().ToList();
                var assessments = conn.Table<Assessments>().ToList();

                termPicker.ItemsSource = terms;


                var dateNow = DateTime.Now;
                if (!terms.Any())
                {
                    conn.Insert(new Terms
                    {
                        TermName = "Demo Term",
                        TermStatus = "In Progress",
                        TProjStart = dateNow,
                        TProjEnd = dateNow,
                        TActStart = dateNow,
                        TActEnd = dateNow
                    });
                }
```

Event Handler

```
            void InfoClicked(Object sender, EventArgs e)

            {
                using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(App.DatabaseLocation))
                {

                    var terms = conn.Table<Terms>().ToList().FirstOrDefault();

                    var pickerItem = termPicker.Items[termPicker.SelectedIndex];

                    DisplayActionSheet(pickerItem, "Ok", null, "Term Status: " + terms.TermStatus,
                    "Projected Start: " + terms.TProjStart.ToString(),
                    "Projected End: " + terms.TProjEnd.ToString(),
                    "Actual Start: " + terms.TActStart.ToString(),
                    "Actual End : " + terms.TActEnd.ToString());


                }

            }
```

Picker Bindings

```
        <StackLayout>

            <Picker x:Name="termPicker"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Terms}"
                    ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding TermName}"
                    Title="Select a term"
                    IsEnabled="True"
                    SelectedItem="{Binding pickerItem}"/>
```

Comment: where do you load the data for `Terms` which is your ItemsSource binding?  And why is `PickerItem` a property on your `Terms` class?  What is the context for the code from xaml.cs - is this in your constructor, or a event handler, or what?

Comment: @Jason The data is loaded into `Terms` on this page using `On Appearing()` via a SQLite Insert. The `PickItem` I originally added that when I was looking into how to store the Picker SelectedItem for future use. Right now, its not doing anything and could be removed. The Xaml.cs is a button clicked event handler. Essentially, I want it to display the ActionSheet with the Term information as a popup on a button click. I can get it to work, just not change based on what the picker selected item is.

Comment: please show the code that loads data into `Terms`.  And you are using two different casings for `pickerItem/PickerItem` - is this the way your code actually reads, or is it a copy error?

Comment: @Jason 
```
var terms = conn.Table<Terms>().ToList();
 var dateNow = DateTime.Now;
                if (!terms.Any())
                {
                    conn.Insert(new Terms
                    {
                        TermName = "Demo Term",
                        TermStatus = "In Progress",
                        TProjStart = dateNow,
                        TProjEnd = dateNow,
                        TActStart = dateNow,
                        TActEnd = dateNow
                    });
                }
```

Comment: That terms is just a local variable.  Where is the Terms that ItemsSource is bound to?

Comment: @Jason you mean `termPicker.ItemsSource = terms;`?

Comment: If you post your code somewhere I’ll take a look.  I can’t tell what you’re doing based on what’s been shown

Comment: @Jason https://github.com/yax51/C971.git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a Picker has a `SelectedItem` property on it, all you need to do is cast it to the correct type.  Then you can access all of the individual properties on `term`

```
void InfoClicked(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var term = (Terms)termPicker.SelectedItem;

  DisplayActionSheet(term.TermName, "Ok", null, "Term Status: " +  term.TermStatus,
                "Projected Start: " + term.TProjStart.ToString(),
                "Projected End: " + term.TProjEnd.ToString(),
                "Actual Start: " + term.TActStart.ToString(),
                "Actual End : " + term.TActEnd.ToString());

}
```